# Swift computed property to return copy of underlying array

Tags: swift

I have a model class written in Objective-C that I'm converting to Swift. It contains an `NSMutableArray` internally, but the method signature for the getter, as well as the actual return value, are `NSArray`. When called, it creates an *immutable copy* to return.

Essentially, I want callers to be able to iterate/inspect the container, but not modify it. I have this test snippet:

```
class Container {
    internal var myItems = [String]()

    func sayHello() {
        "I have: \(myItems)"
    }
}

let cont = Container()

cont.myItems.append("Neat") // ["Neat"]

cont.sayHello() // This causes sayHello() to print: "I have: [Neat]"

var isThisACopy = cont.myItems

isThisACopy.append("Huh") // ["Neat", "Huh"]

cont.sayHello() // This ALSO causes sayHello() to print: "I have: [Neat]"
```

I've been trying to find a way to override the getter for `myItems` so that it returns an immutable copy, but can't seem to determine how.

**Attempt #1**

This produces a compiler error: `Function produces expected type '_ArrayBuffer<(String)>'; did you mean to call it with '()'?`

```
internal var myItems = [String]() {
    var copy = [String]()
    for item in ... { // What to use in the ...?
        copy.append(item)
    }
    return copy
}
```

**Attempt #2**

This also produces a compiler error, because I'm (understandably) redefining the generated getter `Invalid redeclaration of 'myItems()'`:

```
internal func myItems() -> [String] {
    var copy = [String]()
    for item in myItems {
        copy.append(item)
    }
    return copy
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Container {
    private var _myItems: [String] = ["hello"]
    internal var myItems: [String] {
        return _myItems
    }
}

let cont = Container()
cont.myItems.append("Neat") //not allowed
```

It uses a private stored property and a computed property that returns an immutable copy. It's not possible for a stored property to use custom getters.

Comment: This is the other problem I ran into in Attempt #1: access of `self.myItems` produces an infinite recursion, because the getter is calling *itself*.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual use case is, but could you just use `internal var myItems: [String] {
        return self.myItems
    }` It returns an immutable copy of myItems

Comment: No - this has the same problem. Using `self.myItems` calls the getter, which uses `self.myItems`, which calls the getter... Womp womp. :-)

Comment: Can you just add a public computed property (with a different name) that returns an immutable copy of that array?

Comment: I'm familiar with the underscore approach - this will work. Kind of a bummer there's no "direct access" when using a dynamic getter. I suppose that's not how they work though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A better way to [expose mutable properties as immutable](http://wangling.me/2014/11/expose-mutable-properties-as-immutable.html):

```
class Container {
    private (set) internal var myItems: [String]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how the compiler determines that the list itself should be immutable? I can understand that `private(set)` prevents callers from pointing `myItems` to a new list, but I don't quite understand how it knows that (without any occurrence of `let`) the list is also immutable?

Comment: @CraigOtis The same as `myItems` being immutable in @connor's answer — read-only has the same semantics as constant.